# Django - where does the system determine "form" is Authentication Form?

Tags: python, django

Django version 3.0.3

I'm trying to use Django's built-in user authentication system, specifically its login form and view.

Where is `form = LoginForm()` or `form = AuthenticationForm()` line located?

I can't find it in LoginView and AuthenticationForm definition. And I have no other ideas as to where to look into.

I'm just curious about how Django determines the context behind the hood.

Comment: Might be helpful: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/overriding-templates/

Comment: Oh I didn't notice your message. Thank you tho!

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to import build-in Authentication form

   from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
2. You need to make an object for Authentication form and just pass it to render function.

   return render(request, 'user/login.html', {'form': form, 'title': 'Sign In'})

Note: 
without sending form instance to render function the login form won't be displayed
Similar for RegistrationForm also.

Comment: Thank you. 

But the thing is I can't find the line that says "form = LoginForm()", which I'm assuming we need because we need to specify the context. And that's what I would like to know.

Django's built-in system doesn't use render(), instead it does class-based view.

Comment: Nope it depends on you, you can just extend UserModel and u should render to another html

Comment: I mean when using the built-in login system, all we need to do is add "form" variable into "login.html" and add the path to "django.contrib.auth.urls" into settings.py. And this works. And I don't know why this process is working because I can't find the line that defines "form = LoginForm()"

Comment: Yep that's because its already build-in bro

Comment: So you mean because it's built-in, the system doesn't have to have the line "form = LoginForm()"?

Comment: Of course, dude until if you add built-in urls

Comment: Best example https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/06/27/how-to-use-djangos-built-in-login-system.html

Comment: Right there. If you take a look at "Create a login template" which is the third section, it uses "form" inside "login.html", but none of the things written above specify that the variable "form" is the instance of Login Form. And I just wanna know exactly in what file Django defines the variable "form" to display the login form. And also I'm afraid the article is a bit too old. I don't think there is login() view function in that file in those relatively new versions.

Comment: In views.py build in file simple :)

Comment: In django.contrib.auth.views.py file, there seems to be no line that defines "form = LoginForm()"

Comment: build in Django login itself a Django project so it has specific views, URLs etc. (all files)

Comment: It won't be in your app views.py its a separate app now u got it?

Comment: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py

Comment: And that's the file I've been talking about. There is no line that defines "form = LoginForm()"

Comment: It will be inside django modules

Comment: They are using class-based views

Comment: Inside what module?

Comment: You have installed Django rgt? like pip install django

Comment: Actually I figured out the answer. I really appreciate your help. Thank you so much!! And sorry for the long discussion.